# Type '{ children: Element; history: History<unknown>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Failed to compile.

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps | Readonly): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element; history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'.
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element; history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'.
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<...>'.
38 |   public render() {
39 |     return (

> 40 |       
> |               ^^^^^^^
> 41 |         
> 42 |

Tried to use the 'react-router-dom' version 13.x.x and then it start giving this error. On local machine it is working fine but on cloud it is throwing compile error.

Comment: The latest `react-router-dom` version is 6.14.1. It was published 9 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

its typescript error , u haven't declared the typescript properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).